# Trying to decimal.Round result from two decimal? properties

Tags: c#, null

I think I'm not understanding what the null-coalescing operator is really doing because I'm finding this result really bizarre. Background: I've got a class with two properties, the Weight and the Sales and I'm looking to put together a Sales / Weight inline property. The values are coming from a database so they originally start as decimal? and I also need to round the result. decimal.Round requires decimal, not decimal? so I use the ?? to eliminate that possibility, however the result acts as though there is no numerator at all!

The code below has two options and the line commented out gives me back 100 while the uncommented line gives me back the unrounded 1.6666666667 result. Why is this? Note: I think I'm eliminating the possibility of divide by zero with the ternary condition.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
public class Materials
{
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Sales { get; set; }

    public decimal SalesOverWeight => (Weight == null || Weight == 0)
        ? 0.0m
        //: decimal.Round(Sales ?? default(decimal) / Weight ?? default(decimal));
        : (Sales / Weight) ?? default(decimal);
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new Materials
        {
            Weight = 60,
            Sales = 100
        };

        Console.WriteLine(m.SalesOverWeight);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I've got a question: why are you writing SalesoverWeight as a lambda?  It's getting complicated enough that it should probably just be a function.  Then you don't have to get creative with  :/?/?? constructs.  Can't you just write it as a get-only property?

Answer (score 3):

This fragment: `Sales ?? default(decimal) / Weight ?? default(decimal)` will return `Sales`, or if `Sales` is null, then `0/Weight`, or if that is null, zero.

I think what you intended was `(Sales ?? default(decimal)) / (Weight ?? default(decimal))`. Note that you would never want the last part to evaluate to zero (but you already checked that `Weight` is not null or zero above).

EDIT: The reason is operator precedence: division is higher precedence than ?? operator. The full list is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Comment: just to add `Weight.Value` would be better choice instead of `(Weight ?? default(decimal))`

Comment: The operator precedence was key to my understanding what was going on here! It hadn't occurred to me that would be a factor in this.